# Spring - using static final fields (constants) for bean initialization

Tags: spring, definition, javabeans

is it possible to define a bean with the use of static final fields of CoreProtocolPNames class like this:

---

```
<bean id="httpParamBean" class="org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParamBean">
     <constructor-arg ref="httpParams"/>
     <property name="httpElementCharset" value="CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_ELEMENT_CHARSET" />
     <property name="version" value="CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION">
</bean>
```

---

```
public interface CoreProtocolPNames {

    public static final String PROTOCOL_VERSION = "http.protocol.version"; 

    public static final String HTTP_ELEMENT_CHARSET = "http.protocol.element-charset"; 
}
```

---

If it is possible, what is the best way of doing this ?

Comment: Either delete the question or leave it as is, but not something in between. Thanks.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Something like this (Spring 2.5)

```
<bean id="foo" class="Bar">
    <property name="myValue">
        <util:constant static-field="java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Where `util` namespace is from `xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"`

But for Spring 3, it would be cleaner to use the `@Value` annotation and the expression language. Which looks like this:

```
public class Bar {
    @Value("T(java.lang.Integer).MAX_VALUE")
    private Integer myValue;
}
```

Comment: also add the schema location  xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

Comment: Using Spring EL for your XML config this works:  #{T(com.foo.Headers).HEADER_STATUS} as per http://jonstefansson.blogspot.com/2011/02/references-to-static-constants-and.html

Comment: How can we mark a field as private and final when bean is declared by Annotation ?

Comment: can you explain what the `T(Type)` does in your `@Value` annotation? I am unfamiliar with that notation. I've always used `@Value("${my.jvm.arg.name}")`

Comment: I'm still struggling with the benefits of 'cleaner' annotations - the trouble with @Value is, you must re-release your code to change the configuration - wheras using XML you can separately re-release the config, or have different sets of configs, depending on environment.

Comment: @GunjanShah: `@Value` can also be used in an `@Autowired` constructor

Answer (score 29):

Or, as an alternative, using Spring EL directly in XML:

```xml
<bean id="foo1" class="Foo" p:someOrgValue="#{T(org.example.Bar).myValue}"/>
```

This has the additional advantage of working with namespace configuration:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven order="#{T(org.example.Bar).myValue}"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

don't forget to specify the schema location..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">


</beans>
```

Answer (score 6):

One more example to add for the instance above. This is how you can use a static constant in a bean using Spring.

```xml
<bean id="foo1" class="Foo">
  <property name="someOrgValue">
    <util:constant static-field="org.example.Bar.myValue"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

```java
package org.example;

public class Bar {
  public static String myValue = "SOME_CONSTANT";
}

package someorg.example;

public class Foo {
    String someOrgValue; 
    foo(String value){
        this.someOrgValue = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<util:constant id="MANAGER"
        static-field="EmployeeDTO.MANAGER" />

<util:constant id="DIRECTOR"
    static-field="EmployeeDTO.DIRECTOR" />

<!-- Use the static final bean constants here -->
<bean name="employeeTypeWrapper" class="ClassName">
    <property name="manager" ref="MANAGER" />
    <property name="director" ref="DIRECTOR" />
</bean>
```