# Is it possible to Inject Spring Bean into Enum field?

Tags: java, spring, struts-1, java-ee-7

We have a system that uses Struts 1 and is Singleton based using enums.

Now we have a dependency that has been written using Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE that was supposed to be used only with other systems that also uses Spring, that's why all Spring dependencies declared have its scope as provided.

Now the system using Struts 1 is supposed to use this dependency. I declared all Spring dependencies necessary, created my application context but unfortunatelly I'm not able to inject beans into my singletons because they are enums.

That dependency does not offer rest services as I requested.

Here's my applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:/applicationContext-dependency.xml" />

</beans>
```

Here's a class that demonstrates my problem:

```
public enum ItemRemessaUtil {

    INSTANCIA;

    @Autowired
    private BeneficiarioBS beneficiarioBS;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRemessaBS itemRemessaBS;

    @Autowired
    public Boleto inserirItemRemessaMultaDesassociacao(final MultaBean multa) throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        return this.inserirItemRemessa(multa.getNroFatura(), multa.getNossoNumeroItemRemessa(),
                multa.getDataEmissaoBoleto(), multa.getDataVencimentoBoleto(),
                multa.getValorFatura().subtract(multa.getValorDesconto()), multa.getComprador(), TipoOrigem.MULTA);
    }

    @Autowired
    public Boleto inserirItemRemessaOrdemCancelamento(final OrdCancelBean ordCancel)
            throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        return this.inserirItemRemessa(ordCancel.getNrOrdCancel(), ordCancel.getNossoNumeroItemRemessa(),
                ordCancel.getDataEmissaoBoleto(), ordCancel.getDataVencimentoBoleto(),
                BigDecimal.valueOf(ordCancel.getVlOrdem()), ordCancel.getComprd(), TipoOrigem.CANCELAMENTO_VT);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Boleto inserirItemRemessa(final long numeroPedido, final Long nossoNumeroItemRemessa,
            final Date dataDocumento, final Date dataVencimentoBoleto, final BigDecimal valorTotal,
            final ComprdBean comprdBean, final TipoOrigem tipoOrigem) throws BOException, DataAccessException {
        final Boleto boleto = BoletoBancarioFactory.criarBoletoSantander(
                this.beneficiarioBS.construirBeneficiario(tipoOrigem, ConstantesBoleto.CNPJ_RIOPAR, numeroPedido,
                        nossoNumeroItemRemessa, dataVencimentoBoleto),
                BoletoUtil.construirPagador(comprdBean),
                Datas.novasDatas(dataDocumento,
                        TipoOrigem.MULTA.equals(tipoOrigem)
                                ? ParamMultaDesassociacaoBO.retornarQuantidadeDiasVencimentoMultaDesassociacao()
                                : ConstantesBoleto.QUANTIDADE_DIAS_VENCIMENTO_BOLETO_SANTANDER),
                valorTotal);

        if (nossoNumeroItemRemessa == null
                || DateUtil.retornarDataSemHorario(dataVencimentoBoleto).before(boleto.getDatas().getVencimento())) {
            this.itemRemessaBS.inserirItemRemessa(boleto);
        }

        return boleto;
    }
}
```

I have already read some SO questions such as [Inject bean into enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318454/inject-bean-into-enum) and [Using Singleton enum in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521352/using-singleton-enum-in-spring-mvc) and have tried the solutions listed in those but didn't get any luck, my enum fields are always null and unfortunatelly those are the only entry point to the dependency.

What can I do to inject the fields?

Comment: what you need is a class with an enum.

Comment: @efekctive, could you please elaborate your comment in an answer?

Comment: ItemRemessaUtil should be a class with an inner enum. An enum that has so much logic loses its intent

Comment: "An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants" From Java Tutorials. Just that definition prods an IoC container to ignore it during scanning

Comment: ItemRemessaUtil is a singleton widely used in the system, change its implementation would affect a whole bunch of other use cases.

Comment: Well, that I can not help with. Maybe dig deeper in Spring related docs

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Comment: I think it will not be possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478403/can-i-add-and-remove-elements-of-enumeration-at-runtime-in-java

Comment: @efekctive take a look at this answer, I'm about to try that: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187983/1671

Comment: More or less what I suggested. Wrapping them in an class/component. the static part may do the trick. Did it work?