# How to use a static constant as key for `props` in spring bean configuration

Tags: java, spring

I want to use static values from a class as value for `key` for a `props` in spring bean configuration file. Here is an excerpt from my spring bean config file

```
<property name="serviceMappings">
  <props>
   <prop key="portraitMode">portraitMode</prop>
   <prop key="landscapeMode">landscapeMode</prop>
  </props>
</property>

<bean id="portraitMode" class="com.xyz.PortraitMode">
  <propery name="someDependency" ref="someDependency" />
</bean>

<bean id="landscapeMode" class="com.xyz.landscapeMode">
  <propery name="someDependency" ref="someDependency" />
</bean>
```

Now instead of using hard coded values `"portraitMode"` and `"landscapeMode"` while creating `serviceMappings` I want these values to come from constants defined in another class. Is there a way to do this in Spring ?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897819/spring-using-static-final-fields-constants-for-bean-initialization ? I think it's the answer to your question.

Comment: @erkfel :  I don't think that question matches to what I am looking for. It is the `key` in `props` and not an arbitrary property of a bean, I want to use static final values for.