# Inject value in to an annotation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I would like to inject a value in to an annotation. Below I'm using an annotation for an Simple Workflow (SWF) class:

```
@Activities(version = "1.00")
@ActivityRegistrationOptions(defaultTaskList = FlowConstants.NO_DEFAULT_TASK_LIST)
public interface MyActivities {
    ...
}
```

Rather than use a constant, how do I inject a value to use for defaultTaskList?

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify anything else than a constant in an annotation.

---

However, I'm no SWF expert (far from it...), but I think the point of defaultTaskList is to provide the default value. The [javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/annotations/ActivityRegistrationOptions.html) states that you may specify the list on activity invocation:

> **defaultTaskList**: Task list that activity task is delivered through when no task list is 
>   specified on activity invocation.

[Example from amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/running.html) (**tasklist1**):

```
AmazonSimpleWorkflow swfClient = new AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient(awsCredentials);
ActivityWorker worker = new ActivityWorker(swfClient,
                                           "domain1",
                                           "tasklist1");
worker.addActivitiesImplementation(new MyActivitiesImpl());

// Start worker
worker.start();
```

Comment: The default value depends on the context. E.g. if it's on a dev machine the task list will be different than a prod machine, etc. I think it may be possible using http://stackoverflow.com/a/2897856/654495